# XOR Minimal DNF

Tags: xor

R = (Not Y)(X ⊕ Z) + X (Y ⊕ Z) + Y(X ⊕ Z)

I have been trying to simplify this into minimal DNF but I keep getting a term with 3 variables. There is a hint that the solution has terms which all have only two variables each.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the what you were looking for ?

`((~Y^~X^Z)V(~Y^X^~Z))`V`((X^~Y^Z)V(X^Y^~Z))`V`((Y^~X^Z)V(Y^X^~Z))`

I am not sure if this is minimal, though